# Too Much Abstraction/Interfaces

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-access-layer

I am in the process of designing my data access code, the data is going to be stored in RavenDB, and I am trying to see if my current design has too much abstraction with the number of interfaces I am going to have.

I am going to have DTOs that will just hold the data and then I am going to have Entity (or Model, Business, or whatever you call them) objects that will have extra functionality.  I am also going to have an interface per entity defining what data it needs to have.  So for example:

```
interface IUser
{
    string Id { get; }
    string Username { get; }
    string Password { get; }
    bool ResetPassword { get; }
}

class UserDTO : IUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public UserDTO()
    {
        Id = null;
        Username = null;
        Password = null;
        ResetPassword = false;
    }
}

class User : IUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Id = null;
        Username = null;
        Password = null;
        ResetPassword = false;
    }

    public User(IUser user)
    {
        Id = user.Id;
        Username = user.Username;
        Password = user.Password;
        ResetPassword = user.ResetPassword;
    }

    public ResetPassword()
    {
        Id = null;
        Username = null;
        Password = null;
    }
}
```

The reason I want to have an interface for each entity is because I want to make sure the both `EntityDTO` and `Entity` have the required shared data.

Now for retrieving and saving the data, I am going to use the repository pattern.  I am going to have one generic interface called `IDataRepository` and then each entity is going to have is own repository interface.  For example:

```
interface IDataRepository<T>
{
    bool Save(T entity);
    bool Delete(T entity);
}

interface IUserRepository : IDataRepository<IUser>
{
    IUser Load(string key);
    IUser LoadByLogin(string username, string password);
}

class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    bool Save(T entity)
    {
        //save code
    }

    bool Delete(T entity)
    {
        //delete code
    }

    IUser Load(string key)
    {
        //load code
    }

    IUser LoadByLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        //load code
    }
}
```

The reason I want to have a repository interface for each entity is so that I can if I need to use different data storage options for different entities.

Do this seem like too much abstraction?

Comment: Why differentiate `User` and `UserDTO`?

Comment: Do this seem like abstraction? What do you mean? Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: So you load IUser from a repository. What will you do next? Cast it to User? Also from the info provided, there is no evidence DTO's are really necessary.

Comment: sorry about the missing word in my last question, updated

Answer (score 1):

I think this model has its goods and bads.  If your DTO is going to match the Entity, why have the DTO?  In some systems this is something that needs to happen and in others it is a waste of time.  Entities usually have baggage and dont serialize well depending on the ORM.  If you use that interface the mapping between the DTO and Entity can be done with AutoMapper and should work well every time.  Do you need to have the Entity class live in an separate DLL from the DTO?  If so I think your model works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is too much abstraction. Specifically, I do not see a need for the `UserDTO` class of objects.

`IUser` itself should define the complete interface necessary for the data repository to do its job. If the repository is handed an object that implements `IUser`, like `User` for example, then it should be able to store the data just fine. And, since the interfaces are defined at the lowest level, omitting the `UserDTO` object will not create any dependency problems.

Comment: I dont think we know enough about the system to say its too much.  What if this was a DLL that was being distributed around the company for projects, would you still want to pass back the entity that could have hooks on it that you dont want to give access to?

Comment: @CrazyDart - If the OP is concerned that the people who implement the repository layer are going to use reflection on their IUser instance to gain access to restricted functionality, then that is something that should really be spelled out in the question!

Answer (score 0):

What you have, in essence, seems fine to me.

However, unless you have further distinction between the DTO and Entity classes and a clear need to separate the two, I would simply have `User` extends `UserDTO` and remove the interface all together. That way, you remove the code redundancy that you currently have.